# Salesforce date from lightning calender parse in apex

Tags: datepicker, salesforce, apex, lightning

I am passing the lightning date picker value to apex class as a string. In apex trying to parse date to insert into the database but getting an error that date format is invalid. I am doing it the following way.

```
Data startDate = Date.parse(datefromlwc);
```

What is the right way to parse the date from date picker.